# How to fix "Invalid syntax" error for this code

Tags: python

I started to learn python not long ago and there is this "invalid syntax" error that I get when I try to run it. It says something is wrong with the elif command.

I wanted to learn proggraming and thought this was a good start. It is made just so I get the hang of this really basic stuff. I tried typing else if, putting : after the elif and else if, and completely rewritting the code.

```
print("Type name")
user_name = input()
if user_name == "Y":
print("acces denied")
elif user_name == "X":
print("Nope")
else:
print("Hello, " + user_name + "! Have a good day")
```

I would want it to work instead of giving me the "invalid syntax" error message.

Comment: Just fix your indentation, it matters in Python!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing required indentation. Replace:

```
if user_name == "Y":
print("acces denied")
elif user_name == "X":
print("Nope")
else:
print("Hello, " + user_name + "! Have a good day")
```

By:

```
if user_name == "Y":
    print("acces denied")
elif user_name == "X":
    print("Nope")
else:
    print("Hello, " + user_name + "! Have a good day")
```

Hopefully that would just run.

<sub>Works for me.</sub>

<sub><sub>Not if I feed that to Python 2.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is an indentation issue. Try the following code.

**Code:**

```
print("Type name")
user_name = input()
if user_name == "Y":
    print("acces denied")
elif user_name == "X":
    print("Nope")
else:
    print("Hello, " + user_name + "! Have a good day")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Type name
Joy
Hello, Joy! Have a good day

>>> python3 test.py 
Type name
X
Nope

>>> python3 test.py 
Type name
Y 
acces denied
```